# I want my animation starts at a random time using Math.random

Tags: jquery, adobe-edge

I'm trying to create the random varible and them indicate that stops at the variable number.

```
var x;

function myFunction() {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000);
}

sym.stop('x');
```

Comment: Do you want the animation to start or stop? It might help if you provide a bit more context.

Comment: what I need is when  the animation starting between second 0 and second 2

Answer (score 0):

X is a variable, not a string.  Remove the ' ' around x on the last line.

```
var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000);
sym.stop(x);
```